# How to do multiple transaction in one stored procedure for the same data base with different kind of tables SQL sever & C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one sample database with two tables like table1,table2. During calling of a `stored procedure` from `c#` passing some arguments that are inserted in table1. After that select some fields table2 values, and do some arithmetic operations like adding with some digit and multiply etc.after that return that result to C#.

How to do that in a single stored procedure?

Comment: This possible. A stored procedure doesn't have to be one statement. What have you tried? Are you getting errors with your approach?

Comment: I new two using stored procedure i know how to write insert procedure with arguments after that how to merge the next select statment and do arithmetic operation on it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much the same way you would if it wasn't a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dev].[name_of_stored_procedure]
@an_input INT ,
@another_input DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- prevents the rows effected message from being returned. 
    -- Sometimes messes up C#
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    DECLARE @magic_number INT = 47; -- declare something to do math with

    -- insert into a table
    INSERT INTO dev.some_table (   a_column ,
                                another_column
                            )
    VALUES ( @an_input, @another_input );

    -- get everything in that table that has been added for that same date
    -- while doing things to it
    SELECT   st.a_column + @magic_number AS added_to_col ,
            DATEADD(WEEK, @magic_number, st.another_column) AS added_to_date
    FROM     dev.some_table st
    WHERE    st.another_column = @another_input
    ORDER BY @an_input DESC;
END;
```